# Passing TextBox Value to a unique label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just getting into Jquery and I am stuck on a little bit of a bug. In my HTML I generate some H tags and Labels.  These H tags and Labels have an on click function that will take that element whether it be  an H tag or Label and pass it off to a method (setProperties(this)).

This method will   capture what was written inside the input field and assign it to that element. My bug is that after I click on 2 elements it will change to whatever was in the input on both.  I am assuming the elements are now listening to the input field and assigning there text value to what was inside the input field.  I am curious on how I could rearrange my code to make what ever you element you click on. That field will be the unique field to change.

Variables :
Element is the element I click on such as a H tag or Label
the id ChangeText is the input element where you type to change the label or H tags value.

```
function inputfield(element){
    $("#changeText").on("blur",function(){
        $(element).text($("#changeText").val());
    }); 
}
```

Here is a Jfiddle of what my problem is. If you click on two of the test texts and then change the value of the input. It will change both.  I am looking to change only one.
http://jsfiddle.net/QMsQq/5/

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? As well as how your calling the function.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net .Just add your code there

Comment: probably worth explaining the overall goal here. you want to click on an element, then do what with the properties once you have them? you want to match some other elements and give them the same properties?

Comment: code you showed is not what you describe - there is no `onclick` handler, but `onblur` (`onexit`) listener assigned multiple times - every time `inputfield` function is called

Comment: The overall goal is to select a specific element on the page. Change that values Text attribute. Then click on another element and change that text attribute to something else. But I seem to have all elements that I click on change to whatever is on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when the inputfield function is called, you are setting the onblur to fire.

The on function will last after the inputfield function call. Try calling "off" to remove prior set on events from changeText.

```
function inputfield(element){
    $("#changeText").off().on("blur",function(){
        $(element).text($("#changeText").val());
    }); 
}
```

Warning: untested code.

http://jsfiddle.net/QMsQq/6/ Updated your fiddle to show my solution

Comment: If you want to leave the onblur on the input element so that you can change the value multiple times, and you do not want another event handler on the input, then yes.

Another way to do this would be to add a function on click to the elements that saves off the id to a variable. Then whenever the blur occurs, it uses that variable. Then you don't have to change the event handler each time.

Comment: If you want the blur to happen once, and not remain around, you can use "one" instead of "on" and then the handler goes away after a single usage. But that still doesn't solve your problem if they click on several elements pre-blurring.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the element to a variable.

```
var $elem = $('whatever');
```

and pass that as the argument. And I think you want to fire on focus of an element (click).

Also, here is a VERY simple vanilla js example of what I think you're getting at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqf25/3/

Hopefully that helps a smidge.

**Edit:**
ok, for your fiddle:
Your input syntax is jacked. (missing '>' and you don't need '/input' anyway)
Don't use (onClick) in html. Separate your concerns - javascript goes in the script file, not inline. See my fiddle for an example. Although, from reading your latest posts I don't think it's quite what you want - I'm actually a little confused on what exactly you're trying to do...

**Edit 2:**

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/w88xr/3/

I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If I click on say test 1 for instance. I would like to change that text value.  I then want to click on test 2 and change that text value.  The problem is when I click on test1 change the value. Then I click on test2. It will change the text that I was trying to set on test2. To both test1 and test2.  I knew from the start is was a listener type problem. I am just unsure on how to work around it.  I am looking to change the text of each element I click on.

Comment: Ok, what do you want to change the text on the clicked element to?

Comment: What ever is inside the Input field I would like to assign that value to the text value that is currently inside the H tag or label.

Comment: Ok, I added a new fiddle for you to try.

Comment: Sorry I have not been specific enough.  That would work but the other implementation that useSticks has created works exactly how I need it. Thank you for your help though.